# Flash templates with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flash, templates

I have a client who has a purchased a flash template(http://www.templatemonster.com/flash-templates/21220.html) and I am supposed to use that and create a website using asp.net.

How can I use this template in my website.

Thanks,
Kavita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to embed the flash template (SWF) in your aspx page as for example:

```
<object width="400" height="400"
    classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
    <param name="SRC" value="your_template.swf">
    <embed src="your_template.swf" width="400" height="400"></embed>
</object>
```

[Check here more examples how to add flash in your page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_flashobject)

then you can [read the help in that website to know hot use it](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/?s=use%20flash%20template)

Answer (score 0):

you must put a swf file in a folder

Comment: Care to elaborate? As such, this answer is not very helpful.